# tornado one handler blocks for another

Tags: python, tornado

Using python/tornado I wanted to set up a little "trampoline" server that allows two devices to communicate with each other in a RESTish manner. There's probably vastly superior/simpler "off the shelf" ways to do this. I'd welcome those suggestions, but I still feel it would be educational to figure out how to do my own using tornado.

Basically, the idea was that I would have the device in the role of server doing a longpoll with a GET. The client device would POST to the server, at which point the POST body would be transferred as the response of the blocked GET. Before the POST responded, it would block. The server side then does a PUT with the response, which is transferred to the blocked POST and return to the device. I *thought* maybe I could do this with tornado.queues. But that appears to not have worked out. My code:

```
import tornado
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.queues

ToServerQueue = tornado.queues.Queue()
ToClientQueue = tornado.queues.Queue()

class Query(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        toServer = ToServerQueue.get()
        self.write(toServer)

    def post(self):
        toServer = self.request.body
        ToServerQueue.put(toServer)
        toClient = ToClientQueue.get()
        self.write(toClient)

    def put(self):
        ToClientQueue.put(self.request.body)
        self.write(bytes())

services = tornado.web.Application([(r'/query', Query)], debug=True)
services.listen(49009)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Unfortunately, the `ToServerQueue.get()` does not actually block until the queue has an item, but rather returns a tornado.concurrent.Future. Which is not a legal value to pass to the `self.write()` call.

I guess my general question is twofold:

1) How can one HTTP verb invocation (e.g. get, put, post, etc) block and then be signaled by another HTTP verb invocation.

2) How can I share data from one invocation to another?

I've only really scratched the simple/straightforward use cases of making little REST servers with tornado. I wonder if the coroutine stuff is what I need, but haven't found a good tutorial/example of that to help me see the light, if that's indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How can one HTTP verb invocation (e.g. get, put, post,u ne etc) block and then be signaled by another HTTP verb invocation.
>
> 2) How can I share data from one invocation to another?

The new `RequestHandler` object is created for every request. So you need some coordinator e.g. [`queues`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado-queues-queues-for-coroutines) or [`locks`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html#tornado-locks-synchronization-primitives) with state object (in your case it would be re-implementing queue).

`tornado.queues` are queues for coroutines. [`Queue.get`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue.get), [`Queue.put`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue.put), [`Queue.join`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue.get) return Future objects, that need to be "resolved" - scheduled task done either with success or exception. To wait until future is resolved you should `yielded` it (just like in the doc examples  of [`tornado.queues`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue)). The verbs method also need to be decorated with [`tornado.gen.coroutine`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine).

```
import tornado.gen

class Query(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        toServer = yield ToServerQueue.get()
        self.write(toServer)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        toServer = self.request.body
        yield ToServerQueue.put(toServer)
        toClient = yield ToClientQueue.get()
        self.write(toClient)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def put(self):
        yield ToClientQueue.put(self.request.body)
        self.write(bytes())
```

The `GET` request will last (wait in non-blocking manner) until something will be available on the queue (or timeout that can be defined as `Queue.get` arg).

`tornado.queues.Queue` provides also `get_nowait` (there is `put_nowait` as well) that don't have to be yielded -  returns immediately item from queue or throws exception.

Comment: I've just discovered that running on debian testing/stretch, these are available since it has Tornado 4.3 (queues were apparently introduced in 4.2). But they're not available on debian stable/jessie, where the python3-tornado package is for Tornado 3.2. Is there an easy solution for older versions of Tornado? Or do I need to figure out how to get my target machine using a later debian version?

Comment: There is a `toro` (https://toro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), actually that lib was merge into Tornado (4.x) in `tornado.queue` and `tornado.locks` :)