# confused by tornado.concurrent.Future exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, promise, tornado, future

I'm trying to implement a variant of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849128/tornado-one-handler-blocks-for-another) using tornado Futures. The queues a problem, because I don't want to past data being accumulated. IOW, I want the one http request handler to block waiting for result of another that occurs AFTER the original has started.

But I think I'm missing a step.

My code looks like:

```
Events = dict()

class EventHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self, unit):
        # create  future to block on
        future = tornado.concurrent.Future()
        # store the future at a place the produce can find it
        Events[unit] = future
        # block waiting for the future's response
        result = yield future.result()
        # deregister the future
        Events.pop(unit, None)
        self.write(result)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self, unit):
        # fetch the corresponding future if there is one
        future = Events.get(unit, None)
        if future:
            # found one, set the result to pass body over
            future.set_result(self.request.body)
        else:
            print('noop')
        self.write(bytes())
```

What happens is that I get errors that look like:

```
  File "./foo.py", line 44, in get
    result = yield future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 216, in result
    self._check_done()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 294, in _check_done
    raise Exception("DummyFuture does not support blocking for results")
```

Am I not using the Future correctly? Is there an additional step I need to do in configuring it? Am I supposed to make a subclass that implements that `_check_done` behavior? Is my assumption that a tornado `Future` was synonymous with other systems calla a `promise` incorrect? Is there some different way to do this than just using a future/promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
result = yield future
```

Not

```
result = yield future.result()
```

`yield future.result()` is actually equivalent to `yield <whatever is returned by future.result()>`. If the result isn't ready yet, that means that the `result()` API would have to block (meaning, block the tornado event loop) until the result is ready, and `tornado.concurrent.Future` doesn't support that. You can only wait for the result using the non-blocking `yield future` construct.